# VertexArray declaration inside a class

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to create a `struct` containing a point primitive and a method to draw it. However, declaration of a `sf::VertexArray` outside of method doesn't seem to work. The exactly same declaration inside a method works perfectly fine. Here are the code samples and the error. SFML version 2.1

edit: in both cases `using namespace std;` is used.

Works:

```
struct Point
{
    int dot_x, dot_y;
    sf::Color dot_color;
    Point (int x = 50, int y = 50, sf::Color color = sf::Color::Green) {
        dot_color = color;
        dot_x = x;
        dot_y = y;
    }
    virtual void draw() {
        sf::VertexArray dot(sf::Points, 1);
        dot[0].position = sf::Vector2f(dot_x,dot_y);
        dot[0].color = dot_color;
        window.draw(dot);
    }
};
```

Does **not** work:

```
struct Point {
    sf::VertexArray dot(sf::Points, 1);
    Point (int x = 50, int y = 50, sf::Color color = sf::Color::Green) {
        dot[0].position = sf::Vector2f(x,y);
        dot[0].color = color;
    }
    virtual void draw() {
        window.draw(dot);
    }
};
```

Errors (all pointing at the **VertexArray** declaration string):

```
E:\CodeBlocks\Labs\sem3\sfml1\main.cpp|64|error: 'sf::Points' is not a type|
E:\CodeBlocks\Labs\sem3\sfml1\main.cpp|64|error: expected identifier before numeric constant|
E:\CodeBlocks\Labs\sem3\sfml1\main.cpp|64|error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant|
```

Comment: Could you give a pointer please, which of these lines actually is `main.cpp|64|`? Did you maybe miss to include some additional header?

Comment: `sf::VertexArray dot(sf::Points, 1);` in the non-working version is the line in question. If I missed the header, I think the program wouldn't work in either of variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sf::VertexArray dot(sf::Points, 1);
```

This is a declaration of a variable with an initialiser: you can only write those at namespace or function scope. The parser is suitably confused, as you have it in your class scope. It's basically trying to parse it as a function declaration but, since neither `sf::Points` nor `1` are types, this approach ultimately fails also.

You should use the constructor's *member initialiser list* here:

```
struct Point
{
    sf::VertexArray dot;

    Point (int x = 50, int y = 50, sf::Color color = sf::Color::Green)
      : dot(sf::Points, 1)
    {
        dot[0].position = sf::Vector2f(x,y);
        dot[0].color = color;
    }

    virtual void draw()
    {
        window.draw(dot);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the problem.  
So if I have to initialise a variable using a constructor with parameters, declaring the variable without parameters and executing its constructor from elsewhere (constructor of the containing class or one of its other methods) is the correct path?

Comment: @fwiffo: Basically yeah